# Fetch all keys from an array which value totals comes to 100

Tags: php

I have an array like this:

```
$arr = array(25, 30, 50, 15, 20, 30);
```

I want to fetch all keys which values total comes to `100` or if total `100` is not possible mean it will fetch less than `100`.

I need the total 100 like

```
> $array[2]+$array[4]+$array[5]=100
```

My actual need is what combinations are comes to 100

Comment: can we see your JS code?

Comment: This has nothing to do with jQuery, right?!

Comment: just guess the array values from a checkboxs like <input name="test[]" type="checkbox">

Comment: `$array[0]+$array[3]+$array[4]+$array[5]` is not 100, it is 90.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally I got it. There might be better solutions, but it works ...

Your problem is complex. There are 720 possible unique permutation of an array with 6 entries. More entries means more combinations. So I first got all unique permuations and then calculate the possibilies below or equal hundred for each combination.

```
$array = array(25, 30, 50, 15, 20, 30);
// 'permutations' function can be found at the bottom of my post
$permutations = permutations(array_keys($array));
$combinations = array();

foreach( $permutations as $keys ) {
    $current = array("sum" => 0, "keys" => array());

    foreach( $keys as $key ) {
        if( $current["sum"] + $array[$key] <= 100 ) {
            $current["sum"] += $array[$key];
            $current["keys"][] = $key;
        }
    }

    // order the keys and create a hash of them
    // to be sure each combination only exists once in the result
    sort($current["keys"]);
    $combinations[md5(join("", $current["keys"]))] = $current;
}

// remove the hashes from array when finished
$combinations = array_values($combinations);

// the final result
print_r($combinations);
```

For your array, there are 11 possible combinations. Result would be:

```
Array (
    [0] => Array (
        [sum] => 90
        [keys] => Array (
            [0] => 0
            [1] => 1
            [2] => 3
            [3] => 4
        )
    )
    [1] => Array (
        [sum] => 90
        [keys] => Array (
            [0] => 0
            [1] => 2
            [2] => 3
        )
    )
    [2] => Array (
        [sum] => 95
        [keys] => Array (
            [0] => 1
            [1] => 2
            [2] => 3
        )
    )
    [3] => Array (
        [sum] => 95
        [keys] => Array (
            [0] => 0
            [1] => 2
            [2] => 4
        )
    )
    [4] => Array (
        [sum] => 100
        [keys] => Array (
            [0] => 1
            [1] => 2
            [2] => 4
        )
    )
    [5] => Array (
        [sum] => 85
        [keys] => Array (
            [0] => 2
            [1] => 3
            [2] => 4
        )
    )
    [6] => Array (
        [sum] => 100
        [keys] => Array (
            [0] => 0
            [1] => 1
            [2] => 3
            [3] => 5
        )
    )
    [7] => Array (
        [sum] => 95
        [keys] => Array (
            [0] => 2
            [1] => 3
            [2] => 5
        )
    )
    [8] => Array (
        [sum] => 100
        [keys] => Array (
            [0] => 2
            [1] => 4
            [2] => 5
        )
    )
    [9] => Array (
        [sum] => 90
        [keys] => Array (
            [0] => 0
            [1] => 3
            [2] => 4
            [3] => 5
        )
    )
    [10] => Array (
        [sum] => 95
        [keys] => Array (
            [0] => 1
            [1] => 3
            [2] => 4
            [3] => 5
        )
    )
)
```

The used `permutations` function is based on the [php cookbook](http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/webprog/pcook/ch04_26.htm) but changed four your need.

```
function permutations($array, $permutations = array()) {
    if( !empty($array) ) {
        $result = array();

        for( $i = count($array) - 1; $i >= 0; --$i ) {
            $newItems = $array;
            $newPerms = $permutations;
            list($values) = array_splice($newItems, $i, 1);
            array_unshift($newPerms, $values);
            $result = array_merge($result, permutations($newItems, $newPerms));
        }
    }
    else {
        $result = array($permutations);
    }

    return $result;
}
```

Comment: I have tried this, but I cannot get the permutations() function.

Comment: What do you mean by, `cannot get the permutations() function`, @saravankg? The function is posted below the results in the bottom of my post. Or what did not work for you?