# Calculation of possible Solutions inside an php Array: How to improve my Algorithm?

Tags: php, arrays, algorithm, sorting, permutation

**Preamble:**

This question is **not** about to learn PHP, nor is it code that I plan to use in a productive environment. I just want so see and learn better ways to do this work, as I did in my approach. So please only correct my code or show me better, faster or shorter solutions for doing it. The problem itself has already been solved. Thank you!

---

**The Problem:**

Some days ago a user [asked a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38499993/fetch-all-keys-from-an-array-which-value-totals-comes-to-100) here on SO. His problem has got my attention, because I wanted to find a way to solve his needs.

He wanted to get all possible **key** combinations of an PHP `array`, where the **sum of the values** is **100, or as close as possible to 100**. He had given us an example array, which I will use for my examples too:

```
$array = array(25, 30, 50, 15, 20, 30);
```

For example, one result should be `[2, 4, 5]`, because `50 + 20 + 30` is `100`.

```
$sum = $array[2] + $array[4] + $array[5]; // = 100
```

I think the basic idea should be clear. Now let's take a look at my work ...

---

**My Approach:**

So this problem has got my attention as a developer. At first, I thought it would be pretty simple. Just do some addition and check the result. But then I've noticed that there some points to keep in mind ...

There are plenty of combinations to test. For the example array, there would be up to 720 (`6! = 1*2*3*4*5*6 = 720`) possible permutations. To get all possible combinations, I wanted to get all possible permutations of the array first.

But that was only the half truth. Because there could be double values in the array (*as in your example the `30`*), we could not get all possible permutations of the array values, we had to get all possible permutations of the array keys instead.

So I've used the `pc_permut` function of the [php cookbook](http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/webprog/pcook/ch04_26.htm) and modified it for my needs. It will return all possible permutations in an array of keys.

```
/**
 * gets all possible permutations of $array
 * @param array $array
 * @param array $permutations
 * @return array
 */
function permutations($array, $permutations = array()) {
    if( !empty($array) ) {
        $result = array();

        for( $i = count($array) - 1; $i >= 0; --$i ) {
            $newItems = $array;
            $newPerms = $permutations;
            list($values) = array_splice($newItems, $i, 1);
            array_unshift($newPerms, $values);
            $result = array_merge($result, permutations($newItems, $newPerms));
        }
    }
    else {
        $result = array($permutations);
    }

    return $result;
}
```

The result of this function is a multidimensional array, containing all permutations in an ordered key array.

```
Array (
    [0] => Array (
        [0] => 0
        [1] => 1
        [2] => 2
        [3] => 3
        [4] => 4
        [5] => 5
    )
    [1] => Array (
        [0] => 1
        [1] => 0
        [2] => 2
        [3] => 3
        [4] => 4
        [5] => 5
    )
    [...
)
```

So, for now I got all permutations to work with. The calculation of the possible combinations is not so hard at all. I'll just loop through the permutation, increment the sum until they've reached `100` or above and return the key combination.

But I find out that I missed one thing. As I got all possible permutations, there are even some results doubled in the list. To explain, this two results are basically the same:

```
[2, 4, 5]; // 50 + 20 + 30 = 100
[4, 5, 2]; // 20 + 30 + 50 = 100
```

I've ended up sorting the keys after calculation and use them as index in the resulting array. So it would be sure, that every combination only exists once in the result. This is my `combinations` function:

```
/**
 * gets all possible key combinations of $array with a sum below or equal $maxSum
 * @param array $array
 * @param integer $maxSum
 * @return array
 */
function combinations($array, $maxSum) {
    // get all permutations of the array keys
    $permutations = permutations(array_keys($array));
    $combinations = array();

    // loop all permutations
    foreach( $permutations as $keys ) {
        // create a container for each permutation to store calculation
        $current = array(
            "sum"  => 0,
            "keys" => array()
        );

        // now loop through the permutation keys
        foreach( $keys as $key ) {
            // if the addition is still between or equal $maxSum
            if( $current["sum"] + $array[$key] <= $maxSum ) {
                // increment the sum and add key to result
                $current["sum"] += $array[$key];
                $current["keys"][] = $key;
            }
        }

        // to be sure each combination only exists once in the result
        // order the keys and use them as array index
        sort($current["keys"]);
        $combinations[join("", $current["keys"])] = $current;
    }

    // remove the created key-index from array when finished
    return array_values($combinations);
}
```

The execution is simple straight forward:

```
$array = array(25, 30, 50, 15, 20, 30);
print_r(combinations($array, 100));
```

The result is an array, containing all combinations. For our example array there are eleven possible combinations. The result looks like this:

```
Array (
    [0] => Array (
        [sum] => 90
        [keys] => Array (
            [0] => 0
            [1] => 1
            [2] => 3
            [3] => 4
        )
    )
    [1] => Array (
        [sum] => 90
        [keys] => Array (
            [0] => 0
            [1] => 2
            [2] => 3
        )
    )
    [...
```

Since I've written this script as an [answer of the original question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38499993/fetch-all-keys-from-an-array-which-value-totals-comes-to-100/38501519#38501519), I'll ask myself, if there would be another, even better way to do the work. Maybe there is a way without permutations, or a way to exclude same combinations from calculation or the resulting array. I know that I could execute the calculation directly in the `permutations` function too, but this would be basically the same work flow.

I would really like to get some advises, tips or improvements from you. I think here is some potential to improve the script, but I have actually no idea how to. But I'm sure it could be done more simple and straight forward ...

Thanks for your time! :)

Comment: Hmm. I think not completely, because it is not a review. It's about programming and how to, and that will fit to SO. I don't want a review of the code, I wanted other ways, what imo is not well placed in the code reviews ...

Comment: @eisbehr "I would really like to get some advises, tips". Do you know what the knapsack problem, more general packing problems, and dynamic programming are? This is a class of packing problem. It is the knap sack probleam where all items are given equal value.

Answer (score 0):

Sorting the array leads to some possibilities: here is the one i'm thinking of:

I denote a(selectedIndexes) the element composed of all elements of selectedIndexes e.g.
a({25, 30, 30}) = (25, 30, 30)

P(n) is the set of all combinations of the indexes 1 to n and for clarity sake my arrays starts at index 1 (thus P(2)={1, 2, (1, 2)})

I'm using 2 break conditions explained in the pseudocode below. 1st one is the first element of aSorted = the allowed sum.
2nd one is the sum is too small compared to aSorted first element

```
    selectedIndexes = {}
    sum = 100  
    aSorted = {15, 20, 25, 30, 30, 50} //starting values for the example
                                       //to clarify the following function
    aSum = {15, 35, 60, 90}

function n(aSorted, sum, selectedIndexes){
    compute aSum //precisely search in aSum for the index at which
                 //the elements are bigger than sum, and cut
    answer = (P(count(aSum))) X a(selectedIndexes) // with X being the cartesian product

    for (i=count(aSum)+1; i<=count(aSorted); i++){
        newASorted = splice(aSorted, count(aSum))
        // 1st break condition
        if(newASorted is empty) return answer
        // 2nd break condition the new sum < the first element of aSorted
        if (aSorted(i)<sum && sum-aSorted(i)>=aSorted(1)){
            answer += n(newASorted, sum-aSorted(i), push(selectedIndexes,    
            i))
        }
    }
return answer
}
```

The complexity of this algorithm feels quadratic(after a quick check it's more like of order n^log2(n)) in regard to the number of elements in the array

To make it less abstract, let's develop the example(warning i trust the example more than the pseudocode although i didn't see inaccuracies myself in the pseudocode):

n({15, 20, 25, 30, 30, 50}, 100, {}) = P(4) + n({15, 20, 25, 30, 30}, 50, {6}) + n({15, 20, 25, 30}, 70, {5})

Starting by developing the first n function of the right side of the equation

n({15, 20, 25, 30, 30}, 50, {5}) = (P(2) X {6}) + n({15, 20, 25, 30}, 20, {5, 6}) + n({15, 20, 25}, 20, {4, 6}) + n({15, 20}, 25, {3, 6})

n({15, 20, 25, 30}, 20, {5, 6}) = (P(1) X {(5, 6)})  // + n({15}, 0, {2, 5, 6}) (but 0<15) break condition 2

n({15, 20, 25}, 20, {4, 6}) = P(1) X {(4, 6)} // and break condition 2

n({15, 20}, 25, {3, 6}) = P(1) X {(3, 6)} // + n({15}, 5, {2, 3, 6}) (but 5<15) break condition 2

Now developing the second n function of the right side of the equation

n({15, 20, 25, 30}, 70, {5}) = (P(3) X {5}) + n({15, 20, 25}, 40, {4, 5})

n({15, 20, 25}, 40, {4, 5}) = (P(2) X {(4, 5)}) + n({15, 20}, 15, {3, 4, 5})

n({15, 20}, 15, {3, 4, 5}) = P(1) x {(3, 4, 5)} // + n({}, 0, {1, 3, 4, 5}) new break condition aSum is empty

Comment: Thats for sharing your idea. I would lie, if I say I would understand everything. I got no math degree. :) I will take a closer look tomorrow and try to translate it to 'real' code.

Comment: I developed the example to make the idea less abstract (reediting right now) and i noticed the 1st break condition isn't necessary (because aSum has fewer elements after every step). It is met only when newASorted becomes empty which is a better break condition because i supposed  aSorted wasn't empty in the function n.

Comment: i also understood the question the first way (all possible sums under 100 not only the nearest). Luckily my algorithm gives the maximal sets and P(x) is there for giving the subsets, but you can replace P(x) by what i called a(x). But S.Pinkus is right that the problem is the knapsack problem, so known algorithms that solve the knapsack problem are likely way more optimized